# .gitignore: Is it possible to use regex pattern to match at least one more character

Tags: git

My website's .htaccess was not in git, I have a rule to ignore it:

```
.htaccess*
```

Because I have these files

> .htaccess
> .htaccess.local
> .htaccess.online
> .htaccess.testsite

So I use * in .gitignore. Besides, sometimes

> .htaccess_local.txt
> .htaccess_online.txt
> ...

So, one * can do this.

Now I would like to add .htaccess, but still ignore others. I tried

```
.htaccess(.)+
```

It seems not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.htaccess(.)+` doesn't work because `.gitignore` doesn't use regular expression syntax; it [uses](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) shell wildcard (fnmatch) syntax.

I see 2 ways to fix your problem. The simplest is to continue ignoring `.htaccess*` but force add one file (forced adding allows to add ignored files):

```
git add --force .htaccess
```

Tracked files are never ignored even if they match `.gitignore` patterns.

The second way if to ignore all files and unignore the one:

```
.htaccess*
!.htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
.htaccess[.-]*
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a top result on Google and doesn't have the very simple answer.

```
.htaccess*
```

This doesn't work because * matches 0 or more characters. What the original person simply wanted was

```
.htaccess?*
```

? matches a single character. So this ensures it doesn't match the ".htaccess" file but matches all the other examples.

For example I needed to ignore vim .swp files that were being named with .swa .swb .swc etc. Since this is the file extension these can be excluded with

```
*.sw?
```